# View#setVisibility not becoming visible on api < 17

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this custom view (Relative Layout) in which on the basis of some other view height i'm trying to set the alpha and visibility.

My alpha value changes depending upon the view height and I check if my alpha is < CONSTANT(like 0.033) i set the visibility of that view to be gone else visible. Everything works fine on api 18 n above but for some reason it doesn't work on lower api's.

Code looks something like this

```
    if (val< 0.033){
        setVisibility(GONE);
    } else {
        setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        for (int i = getChildCount()- 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            View v  = getChildAt(i);
            v.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            v.invalidate();
        }
    }
    setAlpha(val);
    invalidate();
```

I really need `Visibility.GONE` and `Visibility.VISIBLE` in order to do proper functioning for my views. `Visibility.INVISIBLE` doesn't fulfill my requirement.

I tried printing out the visibility in Logcat it shows VISIBLE in logcat but on actual device it's not.

One more thing if I don't set the VISIBILITY to GONE everything works fine even on lower api's.

*So the main problem is once visibility set to gone I can't make it visible back again*

Attempts:

1. I tried going through all the child views and making them visible. = Doesn't work :(

   ```
       for (int i = getChildCount()- 1; i >= 0; i--) {
           View v  = getChildAt(i);
           v.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
       }
   ```
2. Tried calling invalidate after I set the visibility = Doesn't work :(
3. Tried doing both making the child views visible and calling invalidate after it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code it is like `setVisibility(GONE);`
but it should be like `someView.setVisibility(GONE);`

Comment: I have a custom view in which my class extends relative layout.. So calling someView.setVisibility is same as calling setVisibility(GONE)

Comment: or try using setVisiblity(View.GONE)